# How to fix unexpected node type with ksonnet?

Tags: ksonnet

When I try to set a parameter with ksonnet I get an error

```
ks param set --env=prow workflows name some-name
ERROR Invalid params schema -- did not expect node type: *ast.ApplyBrace
```

My parameters file looks like

```
local params = import "../../components/params.libsonnet";
params {
  components+: {
    // Insert component parameter overrides here. Ex:
    // guestbook +: {
    //   name: "guestbook-dev",
    //   replicas: params.global.replicas,
    // },
    workflows +: {
      name: "some-name",
    },
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a plus to params fixed it.

```
local params = import "../../components/params.libsonnet";
params +{
  components+: {
    // Insert component parameter overrides here. Ex:
    // guestbook +: {
    //   name: "guestbook-dev",
    //   replicas: params.global.replicas,
    // },
    workflows +: {
      name: "some-name",
    },
  },
}
```